# application crash when Minimized and disabled Internet

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-asynctask, crash

I am new to android and developed my first app which fetch some data from server and displays it. It runs properly on phone but when I minimize the app at any point and disable Internet it get crashes saying "Application has been stopped".

What i used is AsyncTask for background processing and Service for notification.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening ? Please help :(

Comment: Post your logcat....

Comment: You need to post some code and the exception from the logcat to be able to tell what is wrong.

Comment: It is running fine on emulator. I am getting the problem when I install and run it on phone. :( cant even post the log